# Error when connecting to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using [node-run-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-run-cmd) package to start the mongodb server in my app.js file. I know this works because I can see the collections on Robomongo when my script is running as well as the mongod.exe in my list of running processes. The problem is trying to connect to the db called testDB. Below is the commented code.

```
//start mongodb server
//this works
var nrc = require('node-run-cmd');
var cmd = '..\\mongodb\\mongod --dbpath '+__dirname+'\\db';
nrc.run(cmd);

//setup
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//connect to mongo
//this fails to connect to db testDB
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if(!err) {
      console.log("connection successful");
   }
   else{
       console.log(err.message)
   }
});
```

Here is the err.message

```
failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here. My assumption is that the db connection is trying before the server has fully started but I am not completely sure.

EDIT:

so that's what it was, timing issue. I tried the following and it connected to the DB. Is there a graceful way of doing this other than what I have here?

```
function connect(){
   var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB';
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (!err) {
         console.log("connection successful");
      }
      else {
         console.log(err.message)
      }

   });
}
setTimeout(connect, 10000);
```

Comment: Check if your mongodb server is running

Comment: It is running according to list of processes and robomongo

Comment: Okay so i think now i got your problem right... Delay connection for a couple of seconds. this is because the mongod is daemon. It doesn't start with a socket to accept connections it takes some time. Also because of being a daemon the parent process will close before complete database boot. BTW the right method is to always keep database running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the callback in the node_run_cmd package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-run-cmd#callback-style).

Place your connect function inside the callback.

You will probably also want to only start express here as well.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work. The server being started wouldn't be considered done i believe

Comment: Oh, you're right.  node-run-cmd probably returns as soon as it gets a good status back from mongod.exe, but it's not yet listening for connections.

There is probably a an npm module for alerting you when the port is available, but you could also use setInterval to try to connect every 500ms.